# Google +1 count as json for a url

Tags: json, google-plus

Is it possible to get the public +1 counts for a specific url from google+ as json or xml? (Something similar to the functionality of the +1 button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, there is no API for getting +1s for a URL.  For now, you can only get plusoners for an activity via [activity.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/get) or [people.listByActivity](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/listByActivity).  We've had reports lately of people.listByActivity not returning the full list, so until we get that fixed I'd stick with pulling the count from activity.get.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no public API method for this. You can show Google that you want such a method by staring the [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=420).

Comment: Abraham, There is any api for do this now?

Comment: There is not. I updated the question with a link to the feature request.