# How can I find out how many +1's does a link have?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-one

Is there an API to find out how many +1's does a link have in Google Plus? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google +1 count as json for a url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198478/google-1-count-as-json-for-a-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not currently a public API method for getting the +1 count for a given URL. You can [open a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list) for one though.