# How to get the number of google plus likes of a website?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

How to get the number of google plus likes of a website from special domain (for example: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/9314534) and to store it in a global javascript variable, so I can insert this number in some javascript functions on my website?

I know it is possible to get the number of facebook likes, hoping it works for google plus too.

A small working example would be greate!
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google +1 count as json for a url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198478/google-1-count-as-json-for-a-url)